# SQL Problem : Assign Guid value to UNIQUEIDENTIFIER

Tags: c#, sql, database

I was trying to assigned the guid data to the uniqueidentifier column but got the issue when assigned with this guid 'ed16e46d-9aaa-4cd9-8c79-d843b5uc246d'. The length and format are correct for guid data but still get the issue 'Conversion failed when converting from a character string to uniqueidentifier.'

Here is my testing script, the first one is the issue value and the section works well.

DECLARE @testA UNIQUEIDENTIFIER = 'ed16e46d-9aaa-4cd9-8c79-d843b5uc246d'

DECLARE @testB UNIQUEIDENTIFIER = '8fc2deba-08f5-4673-9a02-305e92dcb5b1'

Comment: Check the [sql server uniqueidentifier documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/uniqueidentifier-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15). They say you need to convert from an string or use the NEWID or NEWSEQUENTIALID functions.

Comment: Where'd you get the first one; it's not [valid](http://guid.us/Test/GUID).

Comment: The first one is missing a character in the last segment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your second GUID beginning `8fc` is fine.

Your first GUID is *not* valid, A GUID can contain only letters A-F, this GUID contains a `u`.

Check your GUID is valid here: http://guid.us/Test/GUID

Comment: you could mention also that GUID is written in hexadecimal

Comment: Yes a GUID is composed of base-16 digits - the linked resource contains a lot more info.